# Can this be made more efficient?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm pretty green when it comes to php...really the only foray into the subject being working with wordpress. Regardless, I have been looking for a way to essentially echo a php statement such as below if, say the user is logged in. The following essentially echoes a logout link in wordpress.

```
<?php wp_logout_url( home_url());?>
```

Now, I can't just echo the above because the link needs to be customized, in this case, using an Icon from font awesome. Now, I need to essentially use the above as the HREF for an HTML link. I know after searching this site that echoing a php statement within a php statement is something you shouldn't do. I came up with the following and I'm wondering if there is a more effective method. This works by the way.

```
<?php if (is_user_logged_in()) { 
        $Logout =  wp_logout_url( home_url());
        echo '<a href="' . $Logout . '" id="addnewpost"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i></a>';
 }
      ?>
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: wp_logout_url doesn't echo it, it returns it. Quote from Codex: `This Template Tag returns the URL that allows the user to log out of the site.`. There is nothing wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not more effective but with a shorter code:

```php
<?=( is_user_logged_in() ? '<a href="' . wp_logout_url( home_url()) . '" id="addnewpost"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i></a>' : '') ?>
```